# Java array of objects (each object with more than 1 element) How to change 1 element in a particular object

Tags: java, arrays, object, element

Java beginner here.  I have an array of objects and need to be able to change one part of a particular object.    For example:  "A", 95 change it to "A", 96

```
Grade [] grades = {
    new Grade ("A", 95}, 
    new Grade ("B", 90)
};
```

I have the Grade class with Grade constructor, gets and sets

```
Grade(letter, number);
```

I keep trying to code something in the main method and it tells me that I cat access get or set on an Array.

Comment: You can edit the question, better than correcting yourself in comments.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting corrections in comments...

Answer (score 1):

```
Grade [] grades = {
    new Grade ("A", 95}, 
    new Grade ("B", 90)
};
```

creates the array then to access elements it would be:

```
grades[0].getLetter(); // which would return "A"
```